# How to write in asp.net web.config httpRuntime for 3.5 framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss, antixsslibrary

This attribute is new in the .NET Framework version 4.0.I have web.config file in solution with  4.0  version of .Net Framework

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime  encoderType="Web.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder, Web.AntiXss"/>
```

and this works well, but if i change version to 3.5 i get this erorr

```
Unrecognized attribute 'encoderType'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
```

encoderType attribute is only in 4.0 version, how can i rewrite this to 3.5 ?

**EDIT**

Or how can i use microsoft AntiXss library in .net 3.5 projects ?

I use this article for .net 4.0
http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/06/using-antixss-as-the-default-encoder-for-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only for .Net4

```
Gets or sets the name of a custom type that 
        can be used to handle HTML and URL encoding.
```

You must understand that this is an inside change of a function that are called from the core of Net4, this function is not exist on net 3.5 and lower, so its not how they write it, they just not exist.

reference: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.encodertype.aspx

### Some more informations

This parametre actually is an option to replace the class [System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.httpencoder.aspx) that also exist on Net 3.5, but with out the option of core replace it.

The `System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder` is all ready very power full, and the Net.4 actually insert some more features. By replace it with the `AntiXccEncoder` maybe you get some more control but if not, then is not the end of the world (by HG Wells).

Also I check if its possible with some code to replace this call, and seems to me not possible because this is called on too many points, for example its calling on all control attributes !, on url call, on html render, and its so native inside Net4 that is not worth to make so many code to change the HttpEncoder to AntiXccEncoder.

Maybe you need to focus on the page code that you may afraid for attack and be soure to handle the input data correct.

Comment: Is there another way to use this in .net 3.5 ?

Comment: @andronz give me some minutes to check this out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! I will search how to troubleshot my issue.

Comment: @andronz You do not actually have any issue (its not nessesary to add this, they have the HttpEncoder inside it - I run net4 and not have change that! Do you have any other security thread somewhere in some of your pages ?

Comment: I want to prevent xss on my site. And my app is really big so its will be very hard to focus on all controls on pages. With AntiXss i encode all input and output.

Comment: @andronz This is what I say you, that in 3.5 all ready exist the HttpEncoder that do in most of the cases the same work. So you need to focus at one page of you to see if you actually have any thread, or if all ready all is ok. Some extra encode that I have see, is the attributes - do you place attributes base on user input ?

Comment: Oh, i understand - if i dont use attributes on user input - its nothing to wary about? Input and output encodes by default.

Comment: @andronz In general yes, but make a test, at one, two pages, and see if there is any really thread. Look, if you get any input and render it with HtmlDecode, then this is a thread and Xss can not help you on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of .NET earlier than 4.5, you will need to download and include the library as a reference to your project, and then use the earlier library name for the encodeType setting as shown below.

```
<httpRuntime encoderType="Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXssEncoder, AntiXssLibrary" />
```